# Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I updated my knex to version 0.16.2 and bookshelf is 0.14.1 but when I use transactions in bookshelf like :

```
     return  bookshelf.transaction(async function(trx) {
       ... code here
     }
```

I get following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
    at Object.transaction (/Users/abc/Desktop/proj/backend/node_modules/knex/lib/util/make-knex.js:56:31)
    at Object.transaction (/Users/abc/Desktop/proj/backend/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:249:36)
    at Function.addAction (/Users/abc/Desktop/proj/backend/models/User.js:180:30)
```

the problem is

```
const trx = this.client.transaction(container, config);
```

in node_modules/knex/lib/util/make-knex.js:56:31 as this.client returns undefined

which is called by :

```
transaction: function transaction() {
      return this.knex.transaction.apply(this, arguments);
 },
```

in node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:24

basically our bookshelf.client returns undefined. Not Sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: if I degrade knex to 0.14.6 (my previous version) I was able to get it working

Comment: Yes, Bookshelf is not yet compatible with knex 0.15+.

Comment: @devius : any idea where can I find when will Bookshelf be compatible with latest versions of knex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just fixed in Bookshelf 0.14.2: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/releases/tag/0.14.2

Comment: Thank you @devius. Where can I find Bookshelf will be compatbile with knex 0.16 version because we were using whereRecursive with CTE in knex which was fixed in 0.16.1 - 28 Nov, 2018 (knex)  
https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md